# Click button on key up using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am developing a shopping cart using codeigniter. In my cart page I need to update my cart on change in quantity of the item. I am getting the results with the help of button click. 
But my issue is that I need to get the same result on my key up. For that on key up corresponding button should be clicked

[image: Cart page Image]

**View page**

```
    <td>
     <?php echo form_input(array('name' => $items['rowid']."_qty",'id' => $items['rowid']."_qty", 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5'));  ?>
<button class="btn btn-success " id= "<?php echo $items['rowid']."_qty" ?>" onclick="update_cart('<?=$items['rowid'];?>')" >update</button>
 <script>
  $("#<?php echo $items['rowid']."_qty" ?>").keyup(function(event){

     $("#<?php echo $items['rowid']."_qty" ?>").click();

      });
       </script>
    </td>
```

**Script for update cart**

```
function update_cart(itemid)
{ 
  var qty= document.getElementById(itemid+"_qty").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax_controller1/update_cart/'+itemid+'/'+qty+'")?>',
            data: { id:itemid }, 
            success:function(response){
              $("#shoppingcart_container").html(response);
$(".total").click();

     }
  });

}
```

> I just need to click currosponding button on change in quantity input
>   field
>   This is my Demo URL [My website link](http://cableandmedia.com/samajamonline/shopping_cart)

Comment: $(".total").trigger("click");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to add extra code to trigger click event. You can directly put `update_cart` with your `form_input` as

```
<?php 
    echo form_input(array(
            'name' => $items['rowid']."_qty",
            'id' => $items['rowid']."_qty", 
            'value' => $items['qty'], 
            'maxlength' => '3', 
            'size' => '5',
            'onkeyup' => "update_cart('".$items['rowid']."')"
        )
    );  
?>
```

Replace `<td>` tag with above code and try

Comment: I have already tried this idea but onkeyup function not working.

Comment: @YadhuBabu : Do you get attribute `onkeyup` in you dom ?

Comment: I am trying to `alert("kk");` on keyup function. That also not getting

Comment: Its working with `'` now try ? with `'onkeyup' => "update_cart('$items[rowid]')"`

Comment: I am getting error in console `shopping_cart:542 Uncaught ReferenceError: $items is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (shopping_cart:542)`

Comment: Just change here `'onkeyup' => "update_cart('$items[rowid]')"` I can't see your changes ?

Comment: @YadhuBabu : I change my ans try with `'onkeyup' => "update_cart('".$items['rowid']."')"` ?

Comment: check my website link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154579/discussion-between-user2486-and-yadhu-babu).

Answer (score 2):

Check this

```
$("#id_of_field").keyup(function(event){

        $("#id_of_button").click();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code so your problem can be solved :

first you need to give a common class to input for getting value and id of input :

```
   $('.commonclass').on('input',function(e){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");    
      update_cart(id)
   });


function update_cart(itemid)
{ 
  var qty= document.getElementById(itemid+"_qty").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax_controller1/update_cart/'+itemid+'/'+qty+'")?>',
            data: { id:itemid }, 
            success:function(response){
              $("#shoppingcart_container").html(response);
$(".total").click();

     }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
   <?php echo form_input(array('name' => $items['rowid']."_qty",'id' => $items['rowid']."_qty",'onkeyup'=>'clickBtn("<?php echo $items['rowid']; ?>")', 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5'));  ?>
   <button class="btn btn-success " id= "updateBtn<?php echo $items['rowid']; ?>" onclick="update_cart('<?=$items['rowid'];?>')" >update</button>
  <script>
    function clickBtn(id){
         $("#updateBtn"+id).click();
     }
  </script>
</td>
```

This is the easiset way

Answer (score 0):

To call any event you only need to call trigger function and pass event name as parameter.

```
$(".total").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add `onkeyup` property to your input element generation. Sorry, I'm not that fluent in php but you can use the same way you add other properties in: `form_input(array( ..))`

```js
function update_cart(itemid, quantity)
{
  console.log(quantity);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="update_cart('someItemId', this.value)" />
```